# Java OpenCV opening video file issues

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg

I have a grayscale .mkv video, which i want to open with OpenCV in Java, but i get the following errors:

With `return new VideoCapture(path, Videoio.CAP_FFMPEG);`

Errors:

```
[ERROR:0@0.004] global /build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (1108) open Could not find decoder for codec_id=61
[ERROR:0@0.004] global /build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (1140) open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoCapture
```

With `return new VideoCapture(path, Videoio.CAP_DSHOW);` No errors, but
`video.isOpened()` is false

With `return new VideoCapture(path);`

Errors:

```
[ERROR:0@0.005] global /build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (1108) open Could not find decoder for codec_id=61
[ERROR:0@0.005] global /build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp (1140) open VIDEOIO/FFMPEG: Failed to initialize VideoCapture
[ WARN:0@0.122] global C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (923) CvCapture_MSMF::initStream Failed to set mediaType (stream 0, (480x360 @ 1) MFVideoFormat_RGB24(codec not found)
```

I have installed OpenCV and added it as a dependency [using this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLf3ZcFotyA&ab_channel=Makeitnow).

I have also tried adding `...\opencv\build\bin\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455_64.dll` to the native libraries, and also tried using this: `System.load("path\\to\\opencv\\build\\bin\\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455_64.dll");`.

Full code:

```
public class Test {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        System.load("path\\to\\opencv\\build\\bin\\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg455_64.dll");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Mat> frames = getVideoFrames(openVideoFile(args[0]));
        System.out.println(frames.size());
    }
}
```

```
//... different class
public static VideoCapture openVideoFile(String path) {
    return new VideoCapture(path);
}

public static List<Mat> getVideoFrames(VideoCapture video) {
    List<Mat> frames = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat frame = new Mat();

    if (video.isOpened()) {
        while (video.read(frame)) {
            frames.add(frame);
        }
        video.release();
    }

    return frames;
}
```

`ffprobe` result:

```
  Metadata:
    MAJOR_BRAND     : qt
    MINOR_VERSION   : 512
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: qt
    ENCODER         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:01:05.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1511 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: png (MPNG / 0x474E504D), rgb24(pc), 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 6 fps, 6 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      HANDLER_NAME    : DataHandler
      ENCODER         : Lavc56.60.100 png
      DURATION        : 00:01:05.834000000
```

Comment: Can you probe your MKV file with `ffprobe`? If so, posting its output could be useful to find out which codec `codec_id=61` corresponds to. The error is indicating that the codec supported by OpenCV FFmpeg addon. So, you'll likely need to call FFmpeg yourself to decode the file and pipe the raw video frames to your program via ffmpeg subprocess' stdout.

Comment: @kesh i have added the ffprobe result

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that OpenCV's FFmpeg plugin is not built with MPNG codec support. So, you are essentially SOL to get this task done only with OpenCV (you can request OpenCV to support the codec, but it won't be a quick adaption even if you succeed to convince their devs to do so). Here are a couple things I could think of as a non-Java/non-OpenCV person (I typically deal with Python/FFmpeg):

1a) If you have a control of the upstream of your data, change the video codec from MPNG to one with OpenCV support.

1b) Transcode the MKV file to re-encode the video stream with a supported codec within your program

2. Create a thread and call ffmpeg from Java as a subprocess (I think `ProcessBuilder` is the class you are interested in) and load the video data via stdout pipe. FFmpeg can be called in the following manner:

```
ffmpeg -i <video_path> -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray -an -
```

The stdout pipe will receive 480x360 bytes per frame. Read as many frames as you need at a time. If you need to limit the frames, you need to do this in seconds using `-ss`, `-t`, and/or `-to` options.

I'm assuming this video is grayscale as you mentioned (ffprobe is indicating the video is saved in RGB format). If you need to get RGB, use `-pix_fmt rgb24` and the video frame data.

Once you have the image data in memory, there should be an OpenCV function to create an image object from in-memory data.